# Groovy Script - Employee reporting structure - Looping through XML to find required Leader

Tags: xml, groovy

I have two xmls combine together using `<multimap>` nodes. 1st data source sends employee and manager ID information ( node) and 2nd data source sends all leader ID information (only Leader IDs list in  node, leader could be manager's manager or direct manager or 2-up/3-up ) they both combined in `<multimap>` tag.

I want to iterate through `<multimap1>` node's `<PerPerson>`, check manager IDs until I find Leader ID in , once leader ID found add a node in employee record ( node).

Please Help!

XML file:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
<multimap:Message1>    
  <PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>12345</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>67891</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
       </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>67891</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>12123</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
      </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>56789</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>12123</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
       </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>12123</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>67678</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
       </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    </PerPerson>
  </PerPerson>
</multimap:Message1>
<multimap:Message2>
    <rfc:ZZH_LEADER_WF_GET_APPROVERS.Response xmlns:rfc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
        <LEADER>12123</LEADER>
        <LEADER>23234</LEADER>
        <LEADER>34345</LEADER>
        <LEADER>56567</LEADER>
        <LEADER>67678</LEADER>      
    </rfc:ZZH_LEADER_WF_GET_APPROVERS.Response>
</multimap:Message2>
</multimap:Messages>
```

Result needed: in above employee & manager data inside  tags itearte until manager ID is one of the leader IDs in rfc / get approvers list. once found add leader ID tag with ID inside  tags

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>12345</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>67891</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
       </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    <leader>12123<leader>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>67891</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>12123</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
      </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    <leader>12123<leader>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>56789</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>12123</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
       </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    <leader>12123<leader>
    </PerPerson>
    <PerPerson>
    <empId>12123</empId>
    <userAccountNav>
      <UserAccount>
        <user>
          <User>
            <manager>
              <User>
                <mgrEmpId>67678</mgrEmpId>
              </User>
            </manager>
          </User>
        </user>
       </UserAccount>
    </userAccountNav>
    <leader>67678<leader>
    </PerPerson>
  </PerPerson>
```

Code I tried

```
    map = message.getProperties();
   def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String;
def messageLog = messageLogFactory.getMessageLog(message);

 def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(body)

    def ns = new groovy.xml.Namespace('http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge')
def rfcNs = new groovy.xml.Namespace('urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions')
   
//for fast search let map PERNR value to a node that contains it, like internal table
def leaderMap = xml[ns.Message1][0][rfcNs.get("ZHR_GET_AWARD_LEADERS.Response")][0].children().collectEntries{ [it.LEADER_LIST.item.text().replaceFirst("^0+(?!\$)", ""), it] }

  
//itearte msg1 -> find entry in leaderMap -> add node
xml[ns.Message2][0].PerPerson[0].each{p->
def emp = p.PerPerson[0]
def leader = leaderMap[p.PerPerson.userAccountNav.UserAccount.user.User.manager.User.mgrEmpId.text()]
if(leader)
{
 //  def counter = counter + 1
   p.PerPerson.appendNode('leader', null, leader.text() )
}

}
```

ERROR: code is not filtering leader IDs based on match found manager IDs

```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No signature of method:
> groovy.util.NodeList.appendNode() is applicable for argument types:
> (java.lang.String, null, java.lang.String) values: [leader, null, 000000710000008000000184000005020000053000000638000008750000090600001630000125800001341000014010000152800001623000019900000199300002413000030580000340200004157000051720000525300013698000159520001555000162800016170001647000206000021458000215180002278000249080002629400030650004117000417]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you tried and errors you are getting so we can help you.

Comment: sure, I am fine tuning it, will post shortly

Comment: I have updated the code, @daggett any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some things I found wrong in your code:

1. [`NodeList`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/NodeList.html) has no `appendNode`. That's why that error occurs
2. `p` is already one. The `PerPerson` nodes that may be the source of confusion in your code
3. `ZHR_GET_AWARD_LEADERS.Response` tag doesn't exist in the xml provided, so I changed to `ZZH_LEADER_WF_GET_APPROVERS.Response`

What I did to make it work was:

1. Instantiated 'Node' using `new Node(p, 'leader', leader.text())`, thus creating a new node in the xml
2. Removed the call to `children()` and added `collect { it }` before collecting to `leaderMap`
3. Removed `PerPerson` calls inside the loop closure
4. **Created the algorithm to find the employee's leader**

##### [groovyide.com/cpi](https://groovyide.com/cpi/share/v1/7ReLTuNG8FcGq7okarAv4eCuaQjKXcwFCQIKcCBiivbsJfF1vbZ21wGK8u-dtddxCOFRqQ8h1ULgeT89M9xbIU9SZbXure9xcGe1rPbObcRgSoUMY75dadjvK0C5HwchH29XTk921z9Vdjqe8Hg7SpkKI5K0DqiUZEwloCiXrQK_7VkTpZKW40iS2H4cObehc77nHCcsVF0eHFAxpp61WlmjA_hoEkD7iAr8kTHv5IjVKBole0Gn0dz4sNl2cmBOSyUVXd-PU64GZDrHI-W0pCygjcgDjGFewiE2Ihw9fkx4SiAXGgs383Hr46dfGm1nDq_Q4qy266w2vIK97SxHkzMtB57zrUhU2_krNTAhvZ0aNJrYNv92Df7REmzqGvxfgv_0MzAhvZ0abH3Ernl7NVjGoDePtsnKJdMslYprv3Vx0b_ad7s9d3h1tnv11T256h4dDQ-_ucNje0hlEnNJzY5DdlxvqeAt3G3ruNtaQeynEeVKIzS5dZ1yX-ESlWbFzROQmyi6w0CrOJobuMue5dj4kC27Zzg2t3ASPMthim6gnFbm-rV5eSLxzSfwsmPVrQklAVZNXx8xC_oZhCdInzIWr1mzupWIOKFChVTzzBAhfREm2bmCFwlF3jBKYqEAC2DrI2NMFL0hd3ao7w1BbT-VKo4COrVTFTLbGP_V40buB5mSnNQncnJAkpI0FnE8vbOx3PZ5xE6RB2keD-g1GDWA7vn42iOKVAtclP-twX2eQc2vTyvYLkj2mKrPiKlmxhnhY_tYCTyvakAk5K-lrL7GtoHTG0AvjojAb6JasxP9ckJvVVXrrpXsXBruBfcHBC0nxKfVysv3WGVBGdZ-8Ly-130AWmeu1XFgD_rdHpwcwpd-d_DVhZO-C_t7Axc-u_uHZ_j7S_f0OEefH-xDb683qCiU-eaCZ130h3n_nXWHPdOTZQ96VmHlOhZwTaQCSYnwJ8CoAuw-OHKHgyFMCUspqBgIcGwjUBOiW4grEmL-QlUHFv5OIeSKCk4YKPKd0TItLGtUbBZMDeZjxGXRWM3L0fvLUZY2XeUqOvyKT8ezalrO8x6P5uLBajFGfQX36B7MCtDl2C14d9_DKFS20v1QswVNGBZnNxRSe_Db-5-rO2ue91PNs-qYQrRWRyWXMFsoSpcxwDXF4juKLZyP8opEPu6zVJ_-mKM5QWogkpRNqSyzkiYHBXk5LQ0dnj2f0Rp4KZ4E1jtlOkaJnS1RE2IdEvvhcrAXNkhGyhC2cdgAZqsZJZe5-sUshAq7RWGcctxA-3Ad8gD_-VHiDhOxUHYkkSDIeieXfTFcSrAJl6PSWTMeYsr-hpAeqs79Rc1zx0dG-LJkvJmEjEJ1zTC_e1d4NB9gxVN6WlZ6hUL9vMry7KG32YeYj5oBvlaTOlRy8Urd6DFR1uaFy9wyQ1WaoWpmNcIiJCz8g1ZfKk6hUFCF46xQ6HE0gDuqGGK4axbGvTWb_Qk) code

```scala
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;

def Message processData(Message message) {
    def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String
    def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
    def ns = new groovy.xml.Namespace('http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge')
    def rfcNs = new groovy.xml.Namespace('urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions')

    // I HAD TO CHANGE THE LINE BELOW BECAUSE THE XML DIDN't HAVE "ZHR_GET_AWARD_LEADERS.Response"
    //for fast search let map PERNR value to a node that contains it, like internal table
    def leaderMap = xml[ns.Message2][0][rfcNs.get("ZZH_LEADER_WF_GET_APPROVERS.Response")][0]\
                        .collect { it }.collectEntries { [it.text().replaceFirst("^0+(?!\$)", ""), it] }

    // All employee manager's, including the managers themselves
    def upManagers = xml[ns.Message1][0].PerPerson[0].collect { it }.collectEntries { p ->
        [p.empId.text(), p.userAccountNav.UserAccount.user.User.manager.User.mgrEmpId.text()]
    }

    // itearte msg1 -> find entry in leaderMap -> add node
    xml[ns.Message1][0].PerPerson[0].each { p ->
        def manager = p.userAccountNav.UserAccount.user.User.manager.User.mgrEmpId.text()
        def leader = leaderMap[manager]
        while (!leader && manager) {
            manager = upManagers[manager]
            leader = leaderMap[manager]
        }
        def node = new Node(p, 'leader', leader.text())
    }
    message.setBody(XmlUtil.serialize(xml[ns.Message1][0].PerPerson[0]))
    return message
}
```

Comment: Hi Maicon, Thank you. I tried your code as it is but its not working, node is not created.
p is one of PerPerson, need p.PerPerson to get into individual person's details.
I tried appendnode and new node both didnt work
Yeah I changed RFC and forgot to change it in question, but changed in my script.

Comment: I am now confused whether it is possible at all?
each employee record contains manager id, need to traverse manager IDs until I find ID which is equal to leader ID in another message map node <Message map>, in my code or your code where are we traversing manager Id through all employee records? I am confused :(

Comment: I tested the code with the xml you provided and It's working as it should. If you copy the provided xml to the `input.xml` file you'll see the output on the `output.xml` file. This is the `output.xml` after the code is run: https://pastebin.com/NJM9Ed68

Comment: Thank you for your response again. I use Groovy script inside my CPI model so cannot test it as you said so trying to test it in online tool - https://groovyide.com/cpi but I get null pointer exception. I gave input xml in input block and your code in script block.
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: groovyide_com.processData() is applicable for argument types: (com.groovyide.cpi.MessageImpl) values: [com.groovyide.cpi.MessageImpl@59851da8]
Error:
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Yes, it ALMOST works now in groovyide.com/cpi. for the first employee ID - 12345 leader node is not created. As per requirement employee ID 12345's manager is 67891 who is not leader so code should look for 67891's manager who is 12123 who is leader in the leader list so for employee record 12345 <leader> node should be 12123.
your code works perfectly if employee's manager is in leader, if not it is not creating leader node, if manager is not in leader list it should check manager's manager (manager employee record) to see whether manager's manager is in leader list or not. THANK YOU

Comment: Thank you. 
Checking / traversing manager's manager i(f not direct manager is leader) is the difficult part. If you see my code other than adding node and def part I was almost ready with the code, my main issue was checking manager's manager node. 
I am new to scripting and use it very less in my day to day job, only specific to some requirements.
Sure, I will try. If couldn't get it I will open another question with my actual requirement.
Thank you again.

Comment: I think that was the right option, it was useful answer did not solve my actual problem/ question asked. someone else may want to help me so I removed tick mark and clicked arrow (useful) answer.
my question clearly says "iterate until manager id is leader id and then append node".
My question: I want to iterate through <multimap1> node's <PerPerson>, check manager IDs until I find Leader ID in , once leader ID found add a node in employee record ( node).

Comment: Sure, that will save an extra thread for same question. Thank you.

Comment: anyone has any thoughts?
How to traverse through nodes based on ID?

xml[ns.Message2][0].PerPerson[0].each { p ->
 def manager = p.userAccountNav.UserAccount.user.User.manager.User.userId.text()
        def leader = leaderMap[manager]
         if(leader) {
             def node = new Node(p, 'leader', leader.text())
        }else{
           // loop through xml with manager's ID's employee record
           //something like while (leader)
     loop through employee records with manager ID and check with leadermap[manager] everytime it gets manager's manager.
        }
    }